# How to verify a particular user is an Active / Inactive users in “ADB2C” during the user SignIn?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Today we are maintaining the external users active or inactive status in the on prem database. Today we have a requirement to migrate the on-premise existing users to the ADB2C identity store.  In Azure ADB2C, how can we find / filter a particular is in active / inactive status?.
Please suggest if there any feature / or a way that existing to achieve this scenario?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an attribute in B2C called "enabled".

You could set that to "true" or "false".

Users marked as "false" will not be able to login.

The other way is to set up "active" as an [extension attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and set it accordingly.

**Update**

Refer this [custom policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/disable-inactive-account).

Comment: Thank you, Well is there way that we can set the user as inactive after 90 days in ADB2C, If a particular user doesn’t logged in with in 90 days. Please suggest.